# Find string, and replace until next quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have html code that looks a little bit like this example:

```
<div style="font-family:Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11pt;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);">
<span style="color:black;"><ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ol></span>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to basically remove all style="*" data. I'm trying to do this using replace() but I would appreciate some help with wildcards because I don't get it!

This is the output I would like to generate:

```
<div >
<span ><ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ol></span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately trying to figure it out only gets me as far as

```
let b = answer.replace(/style="/g, '');
```

Which is obviously not even half way

Comment: Untested but shouldn't `/style=".*"/g` just do the trick?

Comment: Looks like it does do the trick! Thanks so much! Somehow everything I google about this wants to come up with some crazy complicated example, not a simple one like this

Comment: Actually it needs a small update to only replace until the next double quotes: 

`answer.replace(/style=".+?"/g, '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
answer.replace(/style=".+?"/g, '');
```